# p-value vs beta plot

Tags: regression, p-value

I have explored the impact of noise on one of my datasets by simulating noise. I have created the noise by adding (or subtracting) a random value of the measurement based on the validation data of the instrument I used.

The data is analysed using a simple regression model,

$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \times x$

and while exploring the data, I have plotted $\beta_1$ vs log(p). The result was - at least for me - surprising as I would not have expected such a consistent relationship:

[image: Plot log(p) vs beta]

I have to admit that I struggle a bit to interpret this plot. I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: The closer beta is to 0 the harder is rejecting the null hypothesis that it is equal to 0(higher p value).

Comment: Thank you - the answer to this question seems now to be so obvious that it is almost embarrassing. Should I delete it?

Comment: I think its a nice observation and a solid question. Let the community decide on its relevance.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the procedure you followed by "adding (or subtracting) a random value of the measurement based on the validation data of the instrument I used"? Just what did you do? (2) What relationship did you expect between the p-value and the beta estimates?

Comment: I added a value using the ``runif`` function in R, i.e. 
   dat$x.new <- runif(n,-d,d)
(with d being the expected range; a uniform distribution is most appropriate here).

I did not expect any relationship - it was one of a number of diagnostic plots I made, and I was initially surprised by its simplicity.